# Find the area between two curves (parabola and circle)

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

I am try to solve the next problem:

> Find the area of the region determined by the curves $y^2 = 2x$ and $x^2+ y^2= 1$, which contains the point $\left(\frac{-1}{2},\frac{1}{2}\right)$.

My step:

1. I find the intersections and they are: $x = ${$-1- \sqrt{2}$} and $x = ${$-1+ \sqrt{2}$}

But I need help with carrying out the details of this problem.

Thanks, sorry for the possible mistakes of grammar, as I am also studying English.

Comment: $x$ cannot be negative for intersection points, there will be two points with $x=-1+\sqrt{2}$

Comment: Hint: this is a semicircle and two regions, each of which is the complement of the straightforward-to-obtain area between the curves in [0,1]

Comment: @Piquito the area containing point (-.5,.5) is the pacman like figure

Comment: @Piita: I saw both coordinates positive. Thans you.

Comment: The area is given by  $$\frac{\pi}{2}+2\int_0 ^{0.414}(\sqrt{1-x^2}-\sqrt{2x})dx$$

Comment: I changed the title because I originally thought this question dealt with something similar to what is asked [here](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22Area+of+the+topologist%27s+sine+curve%22) or [here](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22Continuous+curves+and+Lebesgue+measure%22). (Google search links given rather than actual Mathematics Stack Exchange links to avoid linking this question to those questions.)

Comment: @Piquito Sure! Perhaps you want to answer the question based on your compact expression?

Comment: @Piita:_The area is obviously equal to half of the circle (i.e. $\dfrac{\pi(1)^2}{2}$) plus twice the half of the symmetric region in which the "small" area (before integration) is equal to $\Delta A=(\sqrt{1-x^2}-\sqrt{2x})\Delta x$. Sorry for bad English.

Comment: @Piquito Yes! See second comment here, above, where i hinted at this. What I meant was that you may have a go at answering this question, as the supponed compactness of your answer would benefit OP and future audience.

Answer (score 0):

So since $(-1/2, 1/2)$ is in the top-left quadrant, you want the bigger area of the two pieces made by the intersection.

There are surely many ways to go about this, but one way is to find the area(s) of the regions bounded by the two curves and the y-axis, and add to that the area of half the circle. Both of these two smaller areas are equal because $y^2 = 2x$ symmetrically intersects the circle.

We know the area of half the circle is $\frac{π}{2}$, and we can obtain the area of one of the smaller regions by taking the integral from $x = 0$ to the intersection point $x =(\sqrt2- 1)$ of the difference function $f(x) = \sqrt{1 - x^2} - \sqrt{2x}$.

That integral can be split up into $2$ integrals: The first can be solved via a trig substitution of $x = \sin(θ)$ to yield an answer of $\frac{1}{2}\times \left[\arcsin(\sqrt2 - 1) + \sqrt2\times (\sqrt2- 1)^\frac{3}{2}\right]$

The second integral can be solved using reverse-power rule to obtain $\sqrt2\times (\sqrt2-1)^\frac{3}{2}$.

So the area of one of the smaller regions we desire is the first answer I gave minus the second answer. Since there's two of them, we multiply the difference by $2$, and we add $\frac{\pi}{2}$ for the semicircle to get the final answer.

So, the area is
$$\frac{π}{2} + [\frac{1}{2}\times \arcsin(\sqrt2- 1)] - [\frac{1}{2}\times(\sqrt(2)\times (\sqrt2 - 1)^{3/2}]$$
or approximately 1.8722.

Comment: I think you should use latex.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I improved on the readability, and did **not** check for errors in the calcs! Also, I wrote the result differently, so please @Matt G. check if you still agree!